# I am unable to get the command that should help me in running the website on local host

Tags: web, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle

Here is package.json

```
   {
      "name": "complete",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Implemented an ethereum smart contract in Solidity to develop an online MarketPlace 
       where people can buy, sell products, ask for a refund, check transaction status etc. The client side 
       pages are served by a Flask server.",
      "main": "truffle-config.js",
      "directories": {
        "test": "test"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC"
    }
```

Here is the error

```
 npm run test 

> complete@1.0.0 test F:\complete
> echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

"Error: no test specified"
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! complete@1.0.0 test: `echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the complete@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-04T08_30_37_917Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question ... but try running the command:
npm run start

Comment: We have tried this command but still, this is showing the same issue

Comment: Please see to the errors do you know how to resolve such errors.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide test command in the script field.

eg: I use mocha for testing

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha"
}
```